# c# Fitting an image in a square detected in another image

Tags: c#, image, uwp, aforge

So basically i need to make an app that fits a painting in a frame on a wall that's square. I'm using aforge to detect the square and with it's corners i place and resize the image i want to the frame. This is done by pressing the third button which triggers imageAdapt() method. Unfortunately the image is not rescaled to the right size and placed wrongly. Here's my code:

```
    namespace MyFirstJob
{
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public static int a = -1;
    public static int b = -1;
    FolderPicker folderPicker1 = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
    FolderPicker folderPicker2 = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker();
    StorageFolder folder1;
    StorageFolder folder2;
    System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> filesList1;
    System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> filesList2;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        folderPicker1.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        folderPicker2.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        a++;
        folder1 = await folderPicker1.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        filesList1 = await folder1.GetFilesAsync();
        var stream = await 
        filesList1[a].OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        image1.Source = bitmapImage;
    }

    private async void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        b++;
        folder2 = await folderPicker2.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        filesList2 = await folder2.GetFilesAsync();
        var stream = await 
        filesList2[b].OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        image2.Source = bitmapImage;
    }

    private async void adaptImage()
    {
        var stream = await 
        filesList1[a].OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
        WriteableBitmap writableBitmap = new 
        WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
        writableBitmap.SetSource(stream);
        BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();
        blobCounter.MinHeight = 100;
        blobCounter.MinWidth = 100;
        blobCounter.MaxHeight = 600;
        blobCounter.MaxWidth = 600;
        blobCounter.ProcessImage((Bitmap)writableBitmap);
        Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();

        SimpleShapeChecker shapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();

        foreach (var blob in blobs)
        {
            List<IntPoint> edgePoints = 
            blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blob);
            List<IntPoint> cornerPoints;

            if (shapeChecker.IsQuadrilateral(edgePoints, out cornerPoints))
            {
                if (shapeChecker.CheckPolygonSubType(cornerPoints) == PolygonSubType.Square)
                {

                    double lenght = getLenght(cornerPoints[0].X, 
                cornerPoints[0].Y, cornerPoints[1].X, cornerPoints[1].Y);
                    image2.Height = lenght;
                    image2.Width = lenght;
                    image2.Margin = new Thickness(cornerPoints[0].X, 
                     cornerPoints[0].Y, 0, 0);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        adaptImage();
    }

    private double getLenght(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
    }

 }
}
```

When it starts: First button loads the background , second one the painting and then the last one makes it fit the painting
    [image]

After loading the background everything is ok
    [image]

Loading the painting (a random square)
    [image]

The final image where the painting is not fit proprely in the square
    [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't upload the XAML code, I added the following XAML code for testing and it can work well on my side with your code snippet.

```
<Canvas>
    <Image x:Name="image1" ></Image>
    <Image x:Name="image2" ></Image> 
    <StackPanel Canvas.Top="20">
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Click="button1_Click" Content="button1"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="Button2" Click="button2_Click" Content="button2"></Button>
        <Button x:Name="Button3" Click="button3_Click" Content="button3"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Canvas>
```

Code behind are the same. I tested on build 15036. For aforge I'm using [AForge Core 2.2.5.60302](https://www.nuget.org/packages/portable.aforge.core/) and [Imaging 2.2.5.60302](https://www.nuget.org/packages/portable.aforge.imaging/).

But I can reproduce your issue with [`Grid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid) panel as the parent container, and at the same time the `cornerPoints` of square doesn't begin from point `0,0`. Inside a `Grid` panel, child elements are measured and arranged according to their row/column assignments.The image control may be positioned in the middle at default. But the `cornerPoints` of square  is the coordinate relative to the top-left corner of background image, so it may be wrong to calculate the `margin` by `cornerPoints`. `Canvas` is suit for your scenarios. So please check if  you are using a parent container for the `Image` controls that will arrange the image controls , for example, a [`StackPanel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel) or a `Grid`. More details please reference [Layout panels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/layout-panels).